# How to run one Api call after another using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I'm new to Node.js( Java background) trying to use Promises to run one Api call after another. First Api call(fetchIdAPI) will return array of IDs, then for each of this IDs I need to run second API call. This is what I came up with

```
  const _ = require('lodash');
  var Promise = require('bluebird');

  let self = this;

  const mockAPI = id => {
        return self.callMarkRecipeAsUnCookedApi(user_id, id);
  };
 const fetchIdAPI = () => {
    return self.callGetAllCookedApi(user_id);
  };

 const fetchIDList = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(fetchIdAPI));

 fetchIDList()
        .then(idlist => Promise.all(_.map(idList, id => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(mockAPI(id))))))
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
        });
```

But I think I messed up when I call fetchIDList() promise, because if I will pass instead of fetchIdAPI() regular array [1,2,3]. Then everything works fine. Any body out there knows how can I do that?

Comment: If `callGetAllCookedApi()` and/or `callMarkRecipeAsUnCookedApi()` are returning a Promise you don't need to wrap them in a `new Promise()`

Comment: You don't need those `new Promise` wrappers. Just `fetchIdAPI().then(... Promise.all(_.map(idList, id => mockAPI(id)))`

Comment: If you are using node 7 or higher look into async/await in order to resolve (or reject) promises in sequence. I believe that it makes it easier to digest if you are coming from Java or similar programming language. It is different from what you have asked, but I get the feeling that your main purpose is to handle the asynchronous flow of javascript in a "synchronous way".